# Should a DatabaseObjectNotClosedException in StrictMode crash my app?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-strictmode

I don't see FATAL_EXCEPTION or anything like that anywhere. I thought these kind of exceptions were warnings, not errors. Should it crash my app?

Note: the query was running on a *worker thread*.

> 05-18 10:33:05.446 E/StrictMode( 4102): Finalizing a Cursor that has
>   not been deactivated or closed. database =
>   /data/data/com.my.stuff/databases/SomeDatabase.db query = SELECT foo
>   FROM bar
>
> 05-18 10:33:05.446 E/StrictMode( 4102): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application
>   did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That depends on how you configured `StrictMode`.

Comment: I didn't configure StrictMode. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: As is covered in [the `StrictMode` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html), crashing your app is due to `penaltyDeath()`. On Android 4.0+, `detectNetwork()` is configured for `penaltyDeath()` "out of the box", leading to [the ever-popular `NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). I am not aware that any of the VM policies (e.g., `detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()`, `detectLeakedClosableObjects()`) are configured for `penaltyDeath()` out of the box.